# My JS playSound function isn't working when I press a key

Tags: javascript

I'm writing my Javascript KeyBoard Music Player. My Javascript function playSound doesn't work after pressing a key. How should I change this function? The browser devtools is signalling about two errors:

> Blockquote

**Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The element has no supported sources;**

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at playSound.**

> Blockquote

Here's my code:

```
function removeTransition(event) {
  if(event.propertyName !== 'transform') return event.target.classList.remove('playing');
}

function playSound(event) {
  const audio= document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
  const key= document.querySelector(`div[data-key="${event.keyCode}"]`);
  if (!audio) return
  key.classList.add ('playing');
  audio.currentTime= 0;
  audio.play();
  }

const keys= Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.key'));
keys.forEach((key) => key.addEventListener('transitionend', removeTransition));
window.addEventListener('keyup', playSound);
```

Here's my HTML code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset= "UTF-8">
    <meta name= "viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>KeyBoard Music</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="keys">
      <div data-key="65"  class="key">
        <kbd>A</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="83" class="key">
        <kbd>S</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="68" class="key">
        <kbd>D</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="70" class="key">
        <kbd>F</kbd>
      </div>
      <div-data-key="71" class="key">
        <kbd>G</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="72" class="key">
        <kbd>H</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="74" class="key">
        <kbd>J</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="75" class="key">
        <kbd>K</kbd>
      </div>
      <div data-key="76" class="key">
        <kbd>L</kbd>
      </div>
    </div>
    <audio data-key="65" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/21557185/track/101921861?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="83" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/168865/track/1704329?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="68" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/439083/track/3905500?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="70" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/3731841/track/2347643?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="71" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/5670691/track/10892?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="72" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/3534449/track/53121289?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="74" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/9496062/track/61069534?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="75" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/9496062/track/61069514?lang=en"></audio>
    <audio data-key="76" src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/5520153/track/33265818?lang=en"></audio>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the HTML code as well.

Comment: Please format your text correctly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error states you didn't add any sources.

```html
<audio data-key="76">
  <source src="https://music.yandex.ru/album/5520153/track/33265818?lang=en">
</audio>
```

Also, that source isn't valid because it is not a file, you just linked the track website. Also, adding the song to your website is illegal and classified as piracy.